# Regex symbols replace

Tags: regex

I want to replace non-repetitive exact numbers of characters (13 letters or numbers) with whitespace.

For example:

```
"button_id=CGM37AGY8328Y", "button_id=XxXxXxXxXxXxX", ...
```

to be

```
"button_id= ", "button_id= ", ...
```

I am not familiar in regex so I will be very thankful if you can help me:)

Comment: Check *character classes* and *quantifiers* : you need to compose a character class that will match any digit as well as any capital letter, and use a quantifier to represent that it will have to be matched 13 times in a row.

Answer (score 2):

`\w{13}` will match 13 sequence of word characters (alpha, numeric, or underscore _). To replace, in JS you could do:

```
let input = 'button_id=CGM37AGY8328Y';
input.replace(/\w{13}/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Thanks! I did my job with your advise:)